# getting a {_stack: [ array ]} to a string to put into mysql database

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to get a list of titles that was stored in a mysql database to be put into an array, so I can put it into the various commands found in [card-deck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/card-deck) and then save it back to the database.

```
sql = `SELECT * FROM ${brawlname} WHERE brawlid = ("${brawlID}")`;
     con.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
         if (err) throw err; 

         var playerAid = rows[0].playerAid
         var playerBid = rows[0].playerBid
         var playerAname = rows[0].playerAname
         var playerBname = rows[0].playerBname
         var deckanme = rows[0].deckname
         var brawlID = rows[0].brawlid

         console.log(`${deckname} found in database!`)

             if (message.author.id == playerAid) {
                 var playerAdeck = JSON.stringify(list) //I've omitted this in various attempts and went right to .split.

                 console.log(playerAdeck)

                 var playerAdeckarray = playerAdeck.split(", ")

                 var maindeckA = new Deck()

                 maindeckA.cards(playerAdeckarray)

                 console.log(maindeckA)

                 newdeckA = maindeckA.join(", ") //error happens here.

                 console.log(newdeckA)
```

The error I get from the indicated line is

> throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           TypeError: maindeckA.join is not a function

[image]

The first line above is when the list goes through Stringify, the last part is after it goes through the .card method.

So in the example text above, I then take the list of names that is obtained from a mysql query and turn it into a string that then creates the deck object. In another file, I take this list of card names, pull it from the database, shuffle it, then try and transform it into a new string and save it back all to have the same error on the .join(", ") line. The functions work from card-deck, but the way to transform it into a string to put into the database doesn't. Anytime I put something into one of the functions related to card-deck[1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/card-deck) I can't get it to a form that works in the database. I've tried .join, .toString(), etc... and most of them either give me [object Object] or the "is not a function" error.

Thanks for any and all help! :D

Comment: I suspect `maindeckA` is not an array thus doesn't have a `.join` method. You can test this by using `typeof maindeckA` and `Array.isArray(maindeckA)`

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the help! That is correct. It isn't an array. My question is more how can I get it to a form where using .join(", ") is going to work. Using .join on the results from the .cards method I believe would get it to a string to put into the database. I just don't know how to get it from the Deck { _stack: [ array] } format to a form that can be put into . join to get it to a string.

Comment: Why not store `playerAdeckarray` in the array. You don't show any mutations of Deck

Comment: @Jason For this example, I don't need to modify the array. But I am running into the same exact problem when using the "mydeck.shuffle()" method in card-deck. In that one I am changing the deck before saving the newly shuffled deck back to the database. I can't get it from the Deck { _stack: [ array] } format to a string in order to save it to the database.

Comment: You could do this `maindeckA._stack.join(", ")`. But you're just serialising what you inputted. There's also `JSON.stringify(maindeckA)`, with the same problem